# Dividing a image into multiple images of equal pixel data

Tags: python, image, matlab, python-2.7, image-processing

I have a greyscale image `im`

If `total` is the sum of all pixels' values, how do I split `im` into 5 images with the following properties:

- sum of all pixels' values is 1/5 of `total`
- *missing requirements...*
- ...

I am using python. But suggestion in any other language will also be appreciated.

I have used the following code for counting pixel data.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('capture.jpg')
im_grey = im.convert('LA') # convert to grayscale
width,height = im.size

total=0
for i in range(0,width):
    for j in range(0,height):
        total += im_grey.getpixel((i,j))[0]

print "The sum of all pixels' values in im is :" 
print total
print "1/5 of that sum is :" 
print total/5
```

any suggestions should be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by equal pixel values? Are there 201987 px in the image and you want to split into equal areas, or is 201987 the sum of all the pixels and you want to have five images with equal sums?

Comment: @Piglet. I can make you a 27x7481 image any day. I agree that you might have a problem splitting it into 5 equal portions by area though. But you would also have a problem splitting it into portions where each has one fifth of the total value if you have integer pixels for the same reason, hence my initial confusion.

Comment: @OP. Piglet has clarified that you want 1/5 of the total intensity of the image in each portion. You will not be able to get an exact answer, so you need to specify A) how close you want to get, and B) how you want to do the splitting.

Comment: and what do you want to achieve with this anyway?

Comment: see basically I have a robotic coordination system where 5 robots work on an grey scale image to print it on paper. this is the part where I provide the robot with images. I want each robot should have equal workload and ink usage. so the best way is to divide the picture into 5 different pictures with equal pixel data(sum of all the pixel data in the picture)

Comment: You're going to spend more time dividing the image than your robots are processing the image.

Comment: Any other possible solution would be appretiated, anyother way I can use to provide the robots the image.

Comment: Are there constraints on the robots getting in each other's way?

Comment: Or minimum time for ink to dry before next robot tramples on same area?

Comment: What's the use of "missing requirements..." ?

Comment: I guess you could have every robot visit every pixel and each robot lay down 1/5th of the necessary ink and start the robots nicely spaced from each other so the ink can dry. You may end up with registration issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original problem is a hard one. But, looking at the comments you made, I think it is a simple problem. You can scan the image from top to bottom, and sum the pixels. When the sum reaches the sum_all_pixels/5, then you have found the first area. Reset the sum to zero, and continue scanning for the second area. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: See I get ur thing and tried that out,  I am having issues selecting that area. Any possible codes or solutions for that. In python or other language.