# Image Distribution

Tags: image, python-2.7, performance, image-processing

I actually was working on a image distribution project, i am new to image processing. My aim was to write a program to distribute it into 6 parts each having equal pixel data. I wrote the below mentioned code.

```
    from PIL import Image
    import cv2
    im = Image.open('grey.jpg')
    im_grey = im.convert('LA')

    width,height = im.size
    line = []

    j,h,total,c=0,0,0,0

    for i in range(0,width):    
        for j in range(0,height):
            total += im_grey.getpixel((i,j))[0]
            h += im_grey.getpixel((i,j))[0]
        c += 1
        if c==5:
            line.append(h)
            c = 0
            print "LINE : " + str(i) + "=" + str(h)
            h = 0

    average_pix = total/6
    print total
    i,m,j,=0,0,0,
    def image_distribution():
        global i,m,j,d,average_pix,image
        while i<=len(line)-1:

            j=j+ line[i]

            if j>=average_pix :
                img=im.crop((0,m,width,i*5))
                img.save("Images/"+"image"+str(i)+".jpg")
                m = i*5
                j=0

            i+=1
    image_distribution()
```

The code seems to work, but not properly, so I would really appreciate if someone can help me with the script or any better script for the same purpose. 
P.S. I am also trying to write a time efficient program.
Thanks and yes the image "grey.jpg" is a greyscale image.

Comment: Can you give a better description of what you're aiming for?  Is it your job to assign or quantize an image pixel into one of 6 possible intensities in such a way where the distribution of all these 6 intensities is equal?  Also, what is wrong with your code?  *"This code seems to work, but not properly"* is not a valid question to ask.  Stack Overflow questions should be asked where you describe what the problem is - and not for us to figure that out ourselves.

Comment: Srry i am new to stack overflow too. Actually i am a electronics guy and i dont have much coding experience. I planned a swarm robotics project where few robots work together to draw a picture on a sheet of paper. Now I want to divide the image and provide each image to a robot. But i want each robot to use same amount of workload so I want to divide the image based on pixel values while being time efficient. My code doesnt seem to divide into equal pixels. You can take a greyscale image and name it grey.jpg. you will know my problem.

Comment: I still don't quite understand what it is you want.  Is it possible to show us a picture of the final output?  Was my first description of what you wanted accurate, or is it something else that you want?

Comment: I actually want to give a image named grey.jpg to my code. My code should divide the image into six parts (6 different images). The condition being the images might not be equal in dimension but the total pixel data of the six images should be equal

Comment: You have two degrees of freedom (horizontally and vertically) and are using a scalar measure - the pixel area (one degree of freedom) as a means of guiding your image splitting.  Therefore, there are many ways for you to divide up an image into roughly 6 equal chunks.  Do you have a preference horizontally? Vertically?  Do you want the chunks to have an equal aspect ratio?  This is not enough to give a good answer.

Comment: Sorry about my incomplete data friend but not much used to stackoverflow. No i dont have any preferance, i just want six distributions having equal pixel data and no other preference.

Comment: How is this question different from the previous one you asked? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017509/dividing-a-image-into-multiple-images-of-equal-pixel-data

Comment: I didnt have any code at that time, now I wrote the above one but still its not as accurate. If you run the code you will know. The above code divides the images but randomly i guess.  Thanks for trying to help me and sorry that I am not from a coding background and unable to add sufficient information

Comment: So would it be a fair assumption to say that we can figure out what the split point is by summing all of the intensities and dividing by 6, then starting from the first column, have a cumulative sum to sum all of the intensities until we get to this split point, use that as the first image, then repeat the process for the rest of the images?  If this is the case, then this is exactly as the answer seen in your previous question, except you want code for it.  Also, what would happen if you had a completely blank image?  The split point would not be well defined.

Comment: ya I know but as I said i am new to coding and completely amature for coding so can you give me a code solution ill be much thankful. my deadline is august last week and my electronics setup is ready but i am withheld due to this part

Comment: I can whip something up.  I see however that you're using OpenCV (`import cv2`).  Would I be allowed to use `numpy` for this question, as OpenCV requires `numpy` arrays as the datatype?  Also, how come you didn't use OpenCV to read in the image with `cv2.imread`?

Comment: You import any module while you are using python. And about the open CV, i tried to but I failed drastically while using it as said i am new to it. and thanks for your help really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going with our discussion, you would like to decompose your image into 6 separate images.  The total summed intensity for the 6 separate images is equal.  As you don't have a preference for how to decompose the images, I'll be decomposing the image column-wise.  Therefore, each image will have the same number of rows, but the number of columns will be different such that each decomposed image will have more or less the same intensity sum.  Take note however that we may not get exactly the same sum for each image due to the very nature of this algorithm, but the differences should hopefully be minimal.

Because you're able to use any module in Python, I would recommend using NumPy but you can still use Pillow to read in the original image.  Convert the image into a NumPy array first so that we can fully use the NumPy array methods to do what you want.

The process that I will follow is quite simple.

1. Find the total summation of all intensity values in the image and divide this by 6 to determine the "split point".
2. Starting with the first column, find the column sum, then move to the next column and accumulate.
3. When we have a cumulative column sum that surpasses the split point, save this image, reset the cumulative column sum and start the process again from this point.
4. Repeat until we get to the end of the image.
5. Take the extracted images and save them to file.

Without further ado:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Open up the image and convert to grayscale
im = Image.open('grey.jpg').convert('L')

# Convert to a numpy array, convert to floating point for precision
im = np.asarray(im, dtype=np.float)

# Determine the total sum of the pixels
total_sum = im.sum()

# Determine the split point
split_point = int(total_sum / 6)

# Store the images here
data = []

# Counts up how many images we've made so far
count = 0

# Records the column sum
column_sum = 0

# Records beginning coordinate of the split image
x = 0

# Until we've exhausted all of the data...
# Go through each column and determine the cumulative sums
for i in range(im.shape[1]):
    column_sum += np.sum(im[:, i])

    # If the column sum has passed the threshold
    if column_sum >= split_point:
        # Get the image and save it
        data.append(im[:, x : i + 1])

        # Update the variables for the next round
        x = i + 1
        column_sum = 0
        count += 1

    # If we have reached the 5th image, just use the rest
    # of the image data as the last image
    if count == 5:
        data.append(im[:, x:])
        break

# Save the images now
for (i, split_img) in enumerate(data):
    pimg = Image.fromarray(split_img.astype(np.uint8))
    pimg.save("image%d.jpg" % (i + 1))
```

Take note that the intricacy at the end is so that we convert the split images into `uint8` first, then create a Pillow image, then save this to file.  The images are labelled such that they are `imagex.jpg` where `x` is a number from 1 to 6.

Comment: Thank's a lot Sir, it works just fine. It helped me a lot. Also thanks for documentating the code so well.

Comment: If anyone is having error listing   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fromArray', change 'fromArray' to 'fromarray'.

Comment: Certainly and you're welcome. One thing you'll notice with my code is that I always document my code. Good luck!

Comment: Yes. That was an error. I have fixed that in the code. My bad and was a typo. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: @rayryeng Hi Ray, I was reading and, as ever, trying to learn something from your answer but I can't understand one aspect of your answer, but I do not know Python at all, so maybe you could find a minute to tell me why you chose to sum the columns rather than the rows. I thought only FORTRAN stored data in column major format, so I guessed Python uses row major order, and sort of expected you might sum across the image rather than down it which might make memory access strided across cache lines rather than contiguous. I just wondered. Thanks if you have a moment.

Comment: @MarkSetchell completely arbitrary. I could have also chosen rows too. The OP had no preference. If I have the time, I'll try benchmarking and seeing how much of a difference it would make, but I don't think it'll make much of a difference. Then again, I could be wrong and I have been in the past!

Comment: @rayryeng If it was arbitrary, that's fine - no need to redo - I just thought I was missing something. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @MarkSetchell absolutely. You didn't miss anything. I definitely appreciate the sentiment in optimization and your line of thinking is correct. Thanks for the comments!